# Katowice: Tadeusza Dobrowolskiego: Why the road to nowhere?

Tags: poland

A question perhaps only Katowice locals will know.

Taduesza Dobrowolskiego ends mysteriously - four lanes, new road markings and traffic signals directing non existent southbound traffic... from some excavations for a road never built. There seems to be no easy expansion to the north - lots of residential buildings, and no obvious route for a tunnel to connect to.

What's the story with this road to nowhere?

[Google maps link](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Dobrowolskiego,+Katowice,+Poland/@50.2635693,19.0361206,629m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x4716ce33aaa7916b:0x7c17aef88ee04273!8m2!3d50.2641104!4d19.0361363?hl=en)

Comment: In some cases when someone builds a new street builds also predispositions for future extensions. An example is this interchange near Milan, built more than 10 years ago, because in the development plan a motorway should cross the existing freeway in that point. Now the right side is closed and ends in the middle of a field, but in the future it should become a motorway! https://www.google.it/maps/@45.6280992,9.2245223,1184m/data=!3m1!1e3

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about travel.

Comment: @CGCampbell Agreed. Although roads are clearly travel-related, questions about why particular roads have or have not been built are essentially questions of engineering, financing and politics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at satellite images from various mapping services, you can see that this area in Katowice has been built up fairly recently.  ul. Tadeusza Dobrowolskiego is adjacent to the new campus for the [Silesian Museum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silesian_Museum).  The new museum campus opened in 2015, and ul. Tadeusza Dobrowolskiego is an access road for the museum.

The [street itself was officially named on July 30, 2013](https://www.katowice.eu/Strony/ul--Tadeusza-Dobrowolskiego.aspx), which coincides with the period when they were building the new museum campus.

Bing Maps shows the [area before the road was constructed.](https://binged.it/2mrB60R)

Mapquest shows a [more recent satellite photo than Google Maps.](https://www.mapquest.com/search/results?query=dobrowolskiego%20katowice%20poland&boundingBox=50.26639423270515,19.03056263923645,50.262673581315944,19.04169917106628&page=0)

This is an area with future development plans that have not yet been fully realized.  This [article from when construction first began in 2011](http://katowice.naszemiasto.pl/artykul/rozbieraja-familok-bo-startuje-budowa-nowego-muzeum,829430,artgal,t,id,tm.html#c579fd383c3580fd,1,3,5) confirms that the first phase of construction for ul. Tadeusza Dobrowolskiego is to extend from ul. Dudy-Grazca only as far as ul. Nadgórników with future plans to extend it all the way through to ul. Katowicka.

This map shows the [intended road layout in the area.](https://mapa.targeo.pl/katowice%2040-205%20dobrowolskiego%20tadeusza%20,18,19.0361117,50.267366?data=eyJmdHMiOnsicSI6ImthdG93aWNlIDQwLTIwNSBkb2Jyb3dvbHNraWVnbyB0YWRldXN6YSAifSwid2luIjoic2VhcmNoLWZvcm0ifQ==)

Comment: Thanks Eric - I can now see the intended route to ul. Katowicka.